# Referrer-Policy: What header should be used?

Tags: html, security, http-headers

I do not normally configure **Security headers**. I have a website where it's possible to configure the [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) for the server which is adopted on all web pages in the **CMS**. I googled and found out that there are different levels on how the **Referrer-Policy header** could be configured.

```
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer 
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade  
Referrer-Policy: origin  
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin  
Referrer-Policy: same-origin 
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin  
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Referrer-Policy: unsafe-url
```

I wonder if the best practice is to always use `no-referrer` which is the most strict level or if it depends on different areas of use?